# change user to oracle and run sql in a shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, unix

I am a root user and in a shell script I would like to change user to oracle than run a sql script, I tried following;

```
#!/bin/sh

portStatus=`lsof -ni:5060`
if [ ${#portStatus} -ne 0 ]
  then
    sudo -u oracle << EOF
    /oracle/product/102/db/bin/sqlplus -s a513s6p4/a513s6p4 @/oracle/product/102/db/GW_EP_List.sql;
    EOF
  else
    exit
fi
```

it gives me following error;

```
./deneme2.sh: syntax error at line 12: `end of file' unexpected
```

Can you please let me know what might be the problem?

Thanks,
Halit

Answer (score 1):

When using here documents the closing string MUST be at the beginning of the line!

Try

```
#!/bin/sh

portStatus=`lsof -ni:5060`
if [ ${#portStatus} -ne 0 ]
  then
    sudo -u oracle << EOF
    /oracle/product/102/db/bin/sqlplus -s a513s6p4/a513s6p4 @/oracle/product/102/db/GW_EP_List.sql;
EOF
  else
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u oracle /oracle/product/102/db/bin/sqlplus -s a513s..........
```

You don't need EOF here. Execute your `sqlplus` command like above. In this case your `oracle` user must be a `sudo` user.

If `oracle` is a normal user

```
su - oracle -c "/oracle/product/102/db/bin/sqlplus -s a513s.........."
```

A little more about `su` command (From man page):

> The su command is used to become another user during a login session.
>   Invoked without a  username, su defaults to becoming the superuser.
>   The optional argument - may be used to provide an environment similar
>   to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
>   Additional arguments may be provided after the username, in which case
>   they are supplied to the user's login shell. In particular, an
>   argument of -c will cause the next argument to be treated as a command
>   by most command interpreters. The command will be executed by the
>   shell specified in /etc/passwd for the target user.

Comment: What you mean by `su iso sudo` ?

Comment: Dear suku, thanks I tried with `su` iso `sudo` and it worked, however I am wondering if I can run it in silence mode because whenever I run it oracle loging text comes up which bothers me :(

`#!/bin/ksh
.....
    su - oracle -c "/oracle/product/102/db/bin/sqlplus -s a513s6p4/a513s6p4 @/oracle/product/102/db/GW_EP_List.sql";
.....`
---> `WARNING: Do not use computer if you are not authorized.
WARNING: You have been warned.
Sourcing /etc/.profile-EIS.....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `su`. Remember get environment with `su -`:

```
COMMAND="/oracle/product/102/db/bin/sqlplus -s a51... "
su - oracle -c $COMMAND
```

A nice sample  [oracle-base site, Automating Database Startup and Shutdown on Linux Post](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/linux/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-linux.php):

```
case "$1" in
    'start')
        # Start the Oracle databases:
        # The following command assumes that the oracle login 
        # will not prompt the user for any values
        su - $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
        su - $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart
        touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
```